# Change desktop background using WinRT for Windows RT

Tags: windows-runtime

Has anyone figured out how to change the desktop background for the Microsoft Surface using the Windows 8 RT approved programming languages?

Comment: This is not possible, you don't have the necessary rights to tinker with user settings.

Answer (score 0):

[Some](http://www.stardock.com/products/decor8/) have figured it out, but it's not through a standard API. Microsoft made an intentional design choice to limit options.

Comment: That's a desktop app, they cannot run on Windows RT.

Comment: You cannot do it. I was pointing out that some have figured out ways.